# כּרְעוּתֵהּ (with a dagesh in the כּ) or כרְעוּתֵהּ (without the dagesh) in Kaddish?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, kaddish, nuschaot, vilna-gaon

Kaddish starts: יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא. אמן: 
בְּעָלְמָא דִּי בְרָא כִרְעוּתֵהּ

The siddur  HaGr”a has כּרְעוּתֵהּ (with a dagesh in the כּ) and all my other siddurim have כרְעוּתֵהּ (without the dagesh).

Please explain the difference in meaning.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2017/01/kaddish-his-will.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general rule is that letters "בגד כפת" do have a *dagesh* when they appear in the beginning of a word, **unless** the word follows a word that ends with one of the vowels (אהוי), and there's a contextual connection between the two words (for example, "אחרי כן").

So here, by saying "כרעותיה" without a *dagesh*, you are actually saying that the two words "ברא כרעותיה" are connected, which means "[that He has] created according to His will".

This sounds right, but the Vilna Gaon actually says that the "כרעותיה" is not connected to "ברא", but to the beginning of the *kadish* ("יתגדל ויתקדש... כרעותיה") - i.e. that He will be praised according to His will. So there should be a slight pause between "ברא" and "כרעותיה", and therefore the "כ" has a *dagesh*.

Notice that a proof for the Gaon's way is the following prayer we say on Shabbat:

> עַל הַכּל יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ וְיִשְׁתַּבַּח וְיִתְפָּאַר וְיִתְרומַם וְיִתְנַשּא שְׁמו שֶׁל מֶלֶךְ מַלְכֵי הַמְּלָכִים הַקָּדושׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא. בָּעולָמות שֶׁבָּרָא הָעולָם הַזֶּה וְהָעולָם הַבָּא. כִּרְצונו וְכִרְצון יְרֵאָיו וְכִרְצון כָּל בֵּית יִשרָאֵל.

The source for this prayer is [Sofrim 14, 12](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9D_%D7%AA%22%D7%93)/%D7%99%D7%93#.D7.94.D7.9C.D7.9B.D7.94_.D7.99.D7.91), where it would seem that it couldn't be that "וכרצון יראיו" is connected to "ברא", but to the first part of "יתגדל" etc.

**Sources:**

- http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=34821
- http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/4750

Comment: Of course, the Gaon's way is strongly rejected by the expanded text "Kaddish HaGadol" where there is no Kiruteih, just descriptions of the world. If the main request of the initial part of Kaddish were _Yitgadal [adverbs] Kiruteih_ (as the Gaon claims), then after the whole Di Atid Lichadata part the word Kiruteih would appear. But it doesn't.

Comment: In Soferim how do you know Kirtzon Yereiav isn't connected to Tigaleh etc.?

Comment: @DoubleAA Well I wouldn't say it's rejected, there's an omission of "כרעותיה" in the "Kaddish HaGadol" in both cases (i.e. it can't prove/disprove either side). As for the second comment, the text we say based off of it in prayer points to this interpretation, but any which way - the "וכרצון יראיו" isn't connected to "ברא", which should be good enough.

Comment: I don't follow anything you just said. In Kaddish Hagadol we have a more elaborate description of the world, so no need for the short form. It's just "in the world [with properties X]". Kemashmalan that khirutei is a property of the world. And the fact that it's not connected is _not_ good enough because that weakens the entire comparison between that prayer and kaddish. Certainly kaddish hagadol is a better parallel then some random paragraph when taking out the torah.

Comment: If you don't want to use the word "rejected" about the gaon, then fine, but at least admit it's very strongly questioned.

Comment: @DoubleAA I still think the "Kaddish HaGadol" can be explained for example by the fact that He would be praised in the correct way if one understands that (here comes the continuation of the Kaddish HaGadol text). But how would one explain the similarity between the Sofrim's "כרצונו" and the Kaddish's one, knowing that in Sofrim it's not about "ברא"?

Comment: @DoubleAA and of course I agree that there's a question here...

Comment: How to explain Sofrim's use? The simplest answer is we don't need to because Sofrim has different Girsaot all the time and is a relatively late work. More than that, we can speculate as I did above that Kirtzono is going on below (Tiggaleh...) in the original (like the question about the punctuation of [Tishkon Titgadal in Kedusha](http://bit.ly/24DFAOC)), or we can note that there are other places where we ask for praise of God's name without regard to His will (like Modim! ועל כלם יתברך שמך) and there's thus no reason to think that every praise of God's name should have that feature.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but at the end of the day it seems obvious that if forced to choose one of the two sources to be our model for Kaddish, the other Kaddish should be deemed the primary model. Everything further is good Torah, but not for LeMaaseh use.

Comment: @DoubleAA I totally agree, I just think that the omission of "כרעותיה" in the Kaddish HaGadol doesn't necessarily prove that it is connected to "ברא". And even though the Sofrim may have different versions, the ones we have have "כרצונו", just like in the Kaddish, and it is obviously not about "ברא" (even if there's a doubt about what **is** it about). Add to that the fact that it's hard to believe that comparison to the other Kaddish  was ignored by the Gaon. Anyway, thanks for the input, I think both explanations have a reasonable doubt hovering above them.

Comment: I don't think there is any reasonable doubt about my position. (Find me an early opinion who discusses it and I'll reconsider. It's too burning a question for the Gra to never mention it in order to answer it.) I also think you should give fair treatment to the mainstream opinion by noting that the Gaon's proof is not as solid as one might think on first read. Currently this answer reads rather lopsided to one side.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question was about the difference in *dagesh* and its meaning, and I think I gave the appropriate answer, with a "proof" from  the source mentioned. I didn't think then of the Kaddish HaGadol, so it's good that you balanced me out in the comments (I can add it to the main answer if that's what you mean).
But I do think there's reasonable doubt in your claim, as it disregards the Sofrim's version, which is very similar to the Kaddish, and which clearly indicates "כרעותיה" is not on "ברא". You didn't really bring proof otherwise, just your reasoning for the omission of "כרעותיה".

Comment: Which makes more sense to disregard: something "very similar" to Kaddish, or Kaddish itself? You can't get more similar than a text of Kaddish! I don't even know why you make it sound like there is a question here of which to follow. The theme of sanctifying God's name is ubiquitous in Judaism and the fact that there are multiple prayers in that vain doesn't mean they all have to be written with precisely the same formulations. Kaddish is Kaddish and other things are other things.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree with you on the point that the Kaddish of course is a better model for comparison. I just don't think that your conclusion follows directly from the version of Kaddish HaGadol. I mean it's not so clear that the omission of "כרעותיה" in the Kaddish HaGadol means that "כרעותיה" in the regular Kaddish cannot be connected to the "יתגדל" part.

Comment: It's only most reasonable that both Kaddishem would follow BeAlma D- with parallel structures, in this case, descriptors of that Alma. To suggest that only in one of the different Kaddish's do we mention the manner in which we want God's name to be sanctified is bizarre. To use [Seth's formulation](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69052/759), that would be like having יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ כּרְעוּתֵהּ שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא בְּעָלְמָא דִּי בְרָא and in the other יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא בְּעָלְמָא דִּהוא עתיד לחדתא. That's not a priori reasonable at all.