# Whose opinion is followed by those who say כרעותיה in Kaddish without a dagesh in the כ?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, kaddish, nuschaot, vilna-gaon

My [question on kaddish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68843/%EF%AC%BB%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A2%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%AA%D6%B5%D7%94%D6%BC-with-a-dagesh-in-the-%EF%AC%BB-or-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A2%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%AA%D6%B5%D7%94%D6%BC-without-the-dagesh-in-kaddis) was well answered.

The answer said that the Vilna Gaon preferred the word כּרְעוּתֵהּ with the dagesh in the chaf, because that word is not connected to "ברא", but to the beginning of the kadish ("יתגדל ויתקדש... כרעותיה") - i.e. that He will be praised according to His will.

Now the [Mishna Berura 56 (1) [2]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=176) says

> אחר תיבות כרעותיה יפסיק קצת **דתיבות אלו קאי אלמעלה על יתגדל**
>
> After
> the words כּרְעוּתֵהּ one should pause **because those words refer to the
> יתגדל above.**

The words in bold sound very much like the answer to my previous question.

Q1] Does the Mishna Berura pasken that we should pronounce the word כּרְעוּתֵהּ?

Q2] Most of the siddurim I have seen have  כרעותיה without the dagesh. If the answer to Q1 is yes, whose opinion do these siddurim follow?

Comment: I've looked at sefard, ashkenaz, and ari (chabad) and none of them have a dagesh in that chof

Comment: @Dude Ashkenaz isn't one thing. Some "Ashkenaz" have it and some don't.

Comment: @Dude see the [Siddur HaGr"a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21127&st=&pgnum=174)

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2017/01/kaddish-his-will.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your quote of the Mishnah Berurah, he says that one should pause **after** "כרעותיה", since everything up to then constitutes one request, starting from "יתגדל". Then, we begin a new request, starting with "וימליך מלכותיה", etc.

The issue with the *dagesh* discussed in your former question mentions the Gaon's opinion that one should pause slightly **before** "כרעותיה" (as well), because that specific word is connected to the beginning of the request ("יתגדל"), and not to the immediate words before it.