# According to the Vilna Gaon, why doesn't Kaddish open with "יתגדל ויתקדש כרעותיה"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, kaddish, vilna-gaon

[According to the Vilna Gaon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68846/5), the opening line of Kaddish is very disjointed.  So much so, that most people are, ostensibly, mispronouncing one of the words.

Grammatically, it would also work, and it would seem to make more intuitive sense, to say:

> יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ כּרְעוּתֵהּ שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא בְּעָלְמָא דִּי בְרָא

So, according to the Vilna Gaon, why don't we say it this way (alternatively, why *do* we say it the way we do)?

Comment: Why does your way makes more sense grammatically? Is it grammatically improper to put the adverbs/directobjects in that order in the sentence? Sure, language without punctuation is confusing, but I don't know why the current way is grammatically problematic.

Comment: @DoubleAA, edited.  I don't mean that it's grammatically wrong.  I just mean that it would seem to make more sense the other way.  It's very confusing the way it is, at least if you hold like the Gra.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2017/01/kaddish-his-will.html

Comment: @DoubleAA here is a corrected/updated link. 
 https://seforimblog.com/2017/01/kaddish-his-wi/